# uninitialized constant ActionView::TestCase::Behavior with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In `rails 5.2.1.1` when running `rspec spec/services`, I get the following error for each file in `spec/services`:

```
NameError:
#   uninitialized constant ActionView::TestCase::Behavior
```

In view of this [discussion](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1854) I checked for something strange in my helper, but can find nothing to cause this. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was caused by using 'loaded' as a category in an enum. I found this by running an individual file in the spec/services folder, and instead of the `ActionView::TestCase::Behavior` error I get the following error:

```
You tried to define an enum named "status" on the model "User", but this will generate a class method "loaded", which is already defined by ActiveRecord::Relation.
```

The enum declaration was

```
enum status: [:not_loaded, :loaded, :loading, :paused]
```

By changing `:loaded` to something else all the tests in rspec/services passed other than those that actually used `:loaded`.

Comment: People arriving here from a web search: Be aware that _any_ semantic or syntax error seems to be able to trigger this non-specific message; cf. @PJSCopeland's answer below. I saw this when issuing `rspec` to run all my specs at once; with `rspec spec/models/mymodel.rb` I got a much more informative message, pointing me at a syntax error in my `application_helper.rb` file.

Answer (score 3):

I had a bunch of the same errors (`uninitialized constant ActionView::TestCase::Behavior`) pop up at random when I changed an `else … if` block to an `elsif` inside a helper; turned out all I'd done was forget to delete the matching `end`.

So for anyone else coming across this, it could easily be a case of a syntax error that just happens to be in a helper.

Comment: Interesting, what was the error message you were seeing?

Comment: `uninitialized constant ActionView::TestCase::Behavior`.

Comment: Thank you.  Although that was in the title, it turned out the real error, for me, was different.